# How to interpret regression results when there are many dummy variables, not many catergories in one dummy variable

Tags: multiple-regression, biostatistics, categorical-encoding

I am confused my regression results.

My data is something like this.

[image]

I want to see whether the presence of these six species would have significant effects on TD. So, I make every of them be dummy variable. 1 is present, 0 is absent. Then, I made six variables be factor and used R to analyse. I use multiple linear regression model to investigate. Here are some codes and results.

[image]

Comment: What are you confused about?  Please be more specific.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am confused how to expain results. For example, There is a significant symbol on T.repens. What does it mean? It means the presence of T.repens have siginificant effects on TD? Or it means, compared to other variables, It means the presence of T.repens have siginificant effects on TD?